# Two algorithms perform better in different situations so I want to combine them depending on their output

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have two algorithms that provide an estimate of the speed of a particle. One is better when the particle is immobile or moving very slowly, the other one is better when the particle is moving. I don't know whether the particle is moving or not *a priori*.

Based on the values returned by both algorithms, I would like to be able to choose which algorithm's estimate to report.

Below are results of both algorithms on simulated data given various true speed values. The plot shows estimates from both algorithms (algorithm 1 estimates in X-axis, algorithm 2 estimates in Y-axis), with a color indicating which algorithm performed best (red for algorithm 1, blue for algorithm 2):

[image]

My goal is to find threshold values for both algorithms (the dashed lines in the graph are an example,Threshold 1 for Algorithm 1 and Threshold 2 for Algorithm 2) that would allow me to divide the results into quadrants in order to decide which method to use. For example by looking at the picture:

- Algorithm 1 estimate > Threshold1 & Algorithm 2 estimate > Threshold2: use Algorithm 1
- Algorithm 1 estimate < Threshold1 & Algorithm 2 estimate > Threshold2: no information available
- Algorithm 1 estimate < Threshold1 & Algorithm 2 estimate < Threshold2: use Algorithm 2
- Algorithm 1 estimate > Threshold1 & Algorithm 2 estimate < Threshold2: use Algorithm 1

Any suggestions on how this problem could be approached? This is an area that I have little experience in, so would appreciate any leads. Thank you!

Comment: Cross validate the different values for thresholds. But why not do something simpler first and just take the average of the two models?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I will look into cross validation, it's just not something I am as familiar with but from what I am reading, it might be relevant. Average of the two models would not work, as mentioned, one is very good in some situations and not so good in one particular situation, where the second method shines. The average would be mediocre throughout.

Answer (score 1):

You could approach this as a machine learning problem as follows. The dataset consists of three features: algorithm 1 predictions, algorithm 2 predictions, and the ground truth label representing which prediction was closer to the true speed.
Train a decision tree classifier, setting sensible values for the max depth or minimum number of samples per node or leaf. This will produce a decision tree which divides predictions into quadrants (or smaller squares, depending on settings) based on which algorithm is favoured within each region.

Comment: Very helpful, will try this.